# How to call manage audio focus for Android in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am playing audio in my app using the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayer plugin in my Flutter plugin. Now what happens is that when audio in my app starts to play, it does not stop the audio from other apps, which means that it does not request the audio focus. How can I manage Audio Focus from my flutter app?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to ask if you found an answer, or if the answer provided worked for you

Answer (score 0):

You must use `audio_service` that implement `MediaSession` in android.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audio_service